# Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `UnityEngine.GUIText'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and I want to display the lives the player has left on the screen. I keep getting the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to UnityEngine.GUIText" in Unity when I compile the code shown below. I have seen the Update function in the Message class work seamlessly exactly like that in a tutorial so I don't know what my problem is.

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int lives = 3;
}

//

public class Message : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text scoreText;

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Lives: " + GameManager.lives.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the exception is not raised in that part of the code

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! I copy pasted your code and it works flawlessly on my machine. Have you tried restarting Unity and Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you use) and test it again? Sometimes this helps. The error message is a little odd tho. It states you use `UnityEngine.GUIText`, which is different from the `UnityEngine.UI.Text` component. You got any idea where that comes from?

Comment: Restarting Unity did the trick! The code started working seamlessly after the restart. Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you include:
`using UnityEngine.UI;` on top of your code?

Comment: Yup! Apparently restarting Unity and VisualStudio was what I needed lmao. The code started working like magic!

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on an Error to see where it is coming from. You get informations about the **name** of the script and the **line** where the error is coming from. Hope it helps.